# Rename [radio] to [radio-transmission], manually retag most [radio] questions

Tags: support, retag-request

As discussed in [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308281/dealing-with-a-commonly-abused-tag), I'm asking for

1. **Moderator support:** Please rename [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) to [radio-transmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-transmission) in order to eliminate future confusion of [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) with [radio-transmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-transmission).
2. **Community support:** There's about 1,300 question tagged [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio), but if I remove questions from these results that are [very unlikely](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=[radio]%20is%3aquestion%20-[html]%20-[jquery]%20-[javascript]%20-[angularjs]%20-[php]%20-[css]%20-[swift]%20-[button]%20-[forms]) to be about radio transmissions (but about [radio-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-button)), I end up with only about 400. Which says: There's about **1000 questions in need of retagging**. I can't possibly do this alone – if anyone of you could pick a [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) + [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) or [forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms) or [button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) combo and retag a few questions, that'd be awesome.

Comment: Can we also remind people that when re-tagging, they should fix all the other issues that they can, not just spam the main page with tag edits?

Comment: Editors should have 2k, and maybe should rate-limit themselves, say 20 per day like in a review queue. I'd let the question hang around for a few days before doing anything.

Comment: Yes, we need to stress that we don't want to overload the review queue with bulk edits that shouldn't be done by users < 2k anyway. Please don't attempt to edit these questions if you have < 2k rep, it is counter-productive and there are more than enough users > 2k around to help.

Comment: I know "radio-transmission" was suggested on the previous question, but I think that the verb "transmission" may be taken as being too restrictive. What about radio reception? Or radio interference? Or optimization of radio telescope data streams? (I have no idea what I'm talking about...) The point is, the tag suggestion seems narrower than I think you intend it to be.

Comment: @Mogsdad which is why I suggested "radio-frequency" in the answer to the attached.  It is a more catch-all term, and used in the telecom industry (at least in the USA side of the world).

Comment: @Mogsdad: [tag:radio] *currently* refers to wireless transmission of data, following the tag description; I really tried to make the minimal semantic change. For special things like processing of radio signals in software, one should consider tagging with [tag:software-defined-radio], or [tag:signal-processing]. For more signal-theoretical, less programmatical questions, one shouldn't use SO, but e.g. dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I don't fully agree -- "frequency" is a mathematical/physical property of a signal. The point is that questions asked about wireless comm' on SO are probably pretty ignorant of the physical properties of transmission; if they were concerned with the frequency of a transmission, they'd be off-topic on SO (because they'd belong on DSP.se, physics.SE, electronics.SE).

Comment: @psubsee2003: I'd rather see tags describing the *application* of RF; e.g. [tag:ham-radio], [tag:nfc], [tag:adhoc-wireless-networking] as "specializations" of [tag:radio-transmission] then to pick one word out of the "semantic" complex that is radio technology.

Comment: Usage tags make sense - consider radio topics on mobile phones, like [this query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[radio]+mobile+is%3Aquestion). (Another bowl of semantic soup.) Topics like internet radio streaming, integration with cellular, general telephony, power management, media formats, and so on. Some of it _is_ related to radio technology, so application tags should take that into account.

Comment: @psubsee2003 As one who designs radio receivers, I disagree. RF describes a specific band of the e-m spectrum, not the concept of transmitting or receiving signals in that band. If you were asking a question about waveguides, antenna design, interference, reflection, or something like that, then maybe RF would be appropriate (since it actually has more to do with the physical properties of the wave,) but I expect that most tags where RF would really be the appropriate tag name would belong better at EE or physics (or _maybe_ DSP) than SO.

Answer (score 10):

Queries that can help with any community involvement:

#### Retag these questions with [radio-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-button), replacing [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) and [button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button):

- Questions tagged with [radio + button](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bradio%5D+and+%5Bbutton%5D+is%3Aquestion) (<strike>195</strike> <strike>181</strike> <s>168</s> 224)
- Questions tagged with [radio + html but not button](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bradio%5D+and+%5Bhtml%5D+-%5Bbutton%5D+is%3Aquestion) (<strike>113</strike> <s>111</s> 184)
- Questions tagged with [radio + forms but not button or html](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bradio%5D+and+%5Bforms%5D+-%5Bbutton%5D+-%5Bhtml%5D+is%3Aquestion) (<s>49</s> 72)
- Questions tagged with [radio + javascript but not button, html or forms](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bradio%5D+and+%5Bjavascript%5D+-%5Bforms%5D+-%5Bbutton%5D+-%5Bhtml%5D+is%3Aquestion) (<s>70</s>)
- Questions tagged with [radio + jquery but not button, html, forms or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bradio%5D+and+%5Bjquery%5D+-%5Bjavascript%5D+-%5Bforms%5D+-%5Bbutton%5D+-%5Bhtml%5D+is%3Aquestion) (<s>101</s> 107)

Comment: If someone stumbles upon this in 2020 - [tag:radio] + [tag:button] have an upward trend despite best efforts, please assist in cleaning up if you can ( until they are close to 0, they will spring back up )

Comment: @OlegValter the fastest way to fix that is to burninate button

Comment: @Braiam - there is tag cleanup and then there is a drastic measure of burning a tag with 34K questions and decent track record, I am not comfortable with that - if you think that's necessary, you can start a meta request.

Comment: @Braiam - did you talk about the other tag then (I am unsure how to interpret "to burninate button" then)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button Or was this about the [tag:radio]?

Comment: @OlegValter I was on the frequently asked view, which has less questions.

Comment: @Braiam - oh, that explains why you only saw 3K of them :) With 34K I don't think it is currently worth the discussion  ( although both [tag:radio] and [tag:button] could benefit from being split into more contextually defined versions, both are not even programming concepts per se ). That said, finishing whart Mogsdad started might be a starting point in making these tags less broad (an extensive analysis is needed here, I think)

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, I think 'radio' really is the correct name for this tag, though the confusion with radio buttons is indeed unfortunate.

[radio-transmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-transmission) or [radio-communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-communication) would probably be the closest alternative names for this tag, but neither term is really sufficiently broad to describe the entire concept (neither is even a superset of the other, for that matter.)

I don't think the other suggestion of [radio-frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-frequency) would work well, as that term refers specifically to the band within the electromagnetic spectrum ranging from 1 Hz - 3 THz. While the term is used somewhat more broadly than that colloquially, it's still mostly just used in discussions related to the physical properties of a wave, which will usually be off-topic for SO and more appropriate for EE or physics.

I would also note that, unlike with most retag requests, there is no ambiguity with the meaning of the term 'radio,' nor is the term (IMO) too broad. The problem is just that a style of buttons happened to be named after the fact that they used to be common on analog consumer radio receivers decades ago. No one actually calls radio buttons 'radios,' nor would any who knows what they are think that they have anything to do with the concept of radio (aside from the aforementioned etymology.) The problem here just seems to be misuse of the tagging UI, not actual ambiguity or over-broadness of the term as with most retag requests.

Perhaps a warning [along the lines of what is suggested here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222658/271431) would be appropriate for this tag, i.e. something like:

> This tag should only be used for questions regarding radio. For questions regarding GUI controls, use [radio-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-button) instead.

While this could be placed in the wiki excerpt, something more prominent would be nice.

Comment: *I think 'radio' really is the correct name for this tag* I couldn't agree more; however, I don't believe in tag excerpt warnings. The vast majority of the mis-taggers simply didn't bother to read a single word of the excerpt.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Right, which is why I think something more prominent would be good. Maybe display the warning in a red or yellow background text box that appears near the tags list, for example. It could also perhaps have a condition such as not being displayed for high-rep users and/or users who have used the radio tag before, for example.

Comment: what about [tag:radio-signal]? Though, the point of changing it is to stop [tag:radio] from being used improperly, and even if the new name isn't perfect, it will still promote proper tagging.

Comment: @Jakar: [tag:radio-signal] is worse; everything I said about [tag:radio-frequency] applies to that, too.

Comment: @Jakar Agreed with Marcus regarding [tag:radio-signal].