# Trogdor killed the [radio] star

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) tag (currently 1,545 questions) is very unclear and ambiguous. Let's be like MTV and kill it.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No, current questions tagged [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) cover several very different concepts:

- Radio engineering
- Configuring software-defined radio applications
- Streaming online radio programs (e.g. writing players, interfacing with streaming API's, etc.)
- Digital signal processing
- GPS
- Radio buttons in HTML: `<input type="radio" ... />`

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

No, questions are only on-topic if they relate to a *programming* concept that relates somehow. [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) can cover many things that are not programming related, such as hardware-related radio engineering, home GPS receiver configuration, recommendations for home media streaming players, etc.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, because it is so ambiguous. Some questions could be retagged [radio-transmissions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308320/rename-radio-to-radio-transmission-manually-retag-most-radio-questions), questions about HTML radio buttons could be retagged [radio-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-button), and questions about GPS could be retagged [gps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gps).

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, see my list above. [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) refers to several different orthogonal concepts.

This is not a duplicate of [Rename [radio] to [radio-transmission], manually retag most [radio] questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308320/rename-radio-to-radio-transmission-manually-retag-most-radio-questions) as that question is a retag request. This is a burninate request.

Comment: Don't see why this should be burninated. I think the linked question about renaming the tag is a better method and that request is a better place to keep the discussion

Comment: @jontro Make an answer then so people can vote on it. A comment is unlikely to save the tag with +20/-4

Comment: See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308390/7328782 -- radio is unambiguous, we just need to keep an eye out for people tagging [tag:radio] when they mean [tag:radio-button].